# MQL5 iterate over struct

Tags: mql5

Is it possible to iterate over both dimensions of a struct? Being more specific, I was wondering wheather it is possible to iterate over the columns of a struct such as:

```
struct Struct { string NAME; int WERT; double VALUE; datetime TIME; int INT; string TYPE; };

Struct s[];

string cols[]={"NAME","WERT","VALUE","TIME","INT","TYPE" };

s[0].NAME = "B";
s[0].WERT = 10;
s[0].VALUE= 50.00;
s[0].TIME = TimeCurrent();
s[0].INT=5;
s[0].TYPE="Man";

s[1].NAME = "A";
s[1].WERT = 10000;
s[1].VALUE= 40000.00;
s[1].TIME = TimeCurrent();
s[1].INT=100;
s[1].TYPE="female";

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
   for(int j=0; j<=ArraySize(cols); j++)
     {
      s[i].cols[j]; // <-------------------
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SOF!
First of all, it is better to avoid using complex structures such as `string`'s inside the `struct`. Use `class`'es if you want your structures to have `string` values. Use an `char[]` and convert if you really need a `string` in it.
Second, You cannot know how much elements you have inside a `struct` and cannot iterate over that - no refrection, sorry. If I were you, I would convert your `TYPE` to `bool` (`enum` in case "male" and "female" is not enough :) and have an `array` of `long`'s (including `int`, `bool`, `datetime` and any other integer types) and `double`'s (add `float`'s in it) then iterate over size of those two `array`'s.

Comment: thank you! will think about it how I will finally solve it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the `JAson` library for this type of behavior. [linky](https://www.mql5.com/en/code/13663)

Example:

```
#include <jason.mqh>

void OnStart()
{
   CJAVal s;
   s[0]["NAME"] = "B";
   s[0]["WERT"] = 10;
   s[0]["VALUE"]= 50.00;
   s[0]["TIME"] = (int)TimeCurrent();
   s[0]["INT"]=5;
   s[0]["TYPE"]="Man";

   s[1]["NAME"] = "A";
   s[1]["WERT"] = 10000;
   s[1]["VALUE"]= 40000.00;
   s[1]["TIME"] = (int)TimeCurrent();
   s[1]["INT"]=100;
   s[1]["TYPE"]="female";

   Print(s.Serialize());
   for(int i=0; i<s.Size(); i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<s[i].Size(); j++) {
         string key = s[i].m_e[j].m_key;
         printf("%s = string(%s), int(%d), double(%.3f)", 
            key, 
            s[i][key].ToStr(),
            s[i][key].ToInt(),
            s[i][key].ToDbl()
         );
      }
   }
}
```

Although, you're much better off creating a `to_string` method on your `structs` and  `classes`

```
struct Struct { 
   string   name; 
   int      wert; 
   double   value; 
   string   str() {
      return StringFormat("Struct(%s, %d, %.2f)", name, wert, value);
   }
};
```